# swap file full while memory is half empty

Tags: ram, swap, memory-usage

`htop` shows 1gb/2gb used memory and 512mb/512mb used swap.

`cat /proc/sys/vm/swappiness` shows 10 and `cat /proc/swaps` shows

> Filename                                Type            Size    Used
>
> /dev/null                               partition       524288  524288

`grep VmSwap /proc/*/status | sort -n -r --key=2.1 | head -5` shows

```
/proc/25760/status:VmSwap:        333976 kB
/proc/2769/status:VmSwap:         149664 kB
/proc/798/status:VmSwap:           17852 kB
/proc/800/status:VmSwap:           16460 kB
/proc/3725/status:VmSwap:           9648 kB
```

What is taking so much swap? swappiness 10 means to use swap only as close as possible to really need it (low memory) so how come this is not happening? Is it recommended to create a larger swap?

Thanks

edit: `free -m` (after the swap suddenly freed itself, not sure why and how)

```
total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           2048        1311         184           3         552         733
Swap:           512         220         291
```

Comment: Please add the output of `free -m`

Comment: Done but at the moment, it is 1.3gb/2gb memory and 221mb/512mb of swap. I have no idea what made the swap free itself and the memory to gain control.

Comment: The swap decreased because data was either read back into memory, as the process was used, or the process released the memory for some reason. The real problem here is that you have rather small RAM for modern use, and you also have quite small swap space. Your problem is not how Linux manages RAM.

Comment: It was clam which calmed down. As you can see, even now, 2gb ram is enough for my need but I will increase the swap. Please read my comment below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small amount of RAM, and rather small swap.

That means that if you have a lot of programs open, or even a single browser with 5-6 tabs it will fill up the RAM. This leads to pressure to swap out stuff that is not in active use.

To make more sense of it, you should check which programs are hiding behind the PIDs you list. This can be checked with `ps aux -q pidno` which will additionally show you total memory useage by that process, user, and so forth.

When things are swapped out, there's no reason to read it in again before it's needed. Some software that is nominally running on your computer, may in reality be totally unused. Swapping such software makes sense.

On my laptop, right now, I have 8GiB of RAM, 4GiB available, and 1.5GiB of swap in use. Mysql is one of the things that is swapped out for me, which makes sense; I use it for development once a week, not every day.

In your case, you have a low amount of memory, and a low amount of swap. I would increase swap to the same amount as memory, at least, in your situation. This allows for better memory management by the kernel.

Some software, such as browsers, require large amounts of RAM. Chrome, with ten Ask Ubuntu tabs, and facebook open consumes close to 3GiB on my laptop.

To add more swap, you can simply use the following commands:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1M count=2048
sudo chmod 600 /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
echo "/swapfile    none    swap    sw    0   0" | sudo tee -a /etc/fstab
sudo swapon -a
```

`swapon -s` should now show your new swapfile. `bs=1M count=2048` will create a 2048MiB file. Modify to suit your needs.

Comment: Using your ps aux -q command made me realize that clamav took the swap. Now clam calmed down and it's back to 212/512. So back to your comment, how can I increase the swap? I read about creating a file and activating the swap to it but since now it's dev/null partition, I want to make sure I'm not ruining things. Also, can this be done without restarting? Thanks

Comment: @amos please see my eidt.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Appreciated!

Comment: I'm root and with sudo and still I get "sudo swapon -a" -> swapon: /swapfile: swapon failed: Operation not permitted. It's a VPS. I will ask the provider.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Article Credit goes to this : [Article Link](https://www.vishalon.net/blog/webmin-how-to-change-the-size-of-swap)

**Webmin: How to change the size of Swap?**

January 6, 2020Category:Linux AdministrationTags:linux, swap, virtualmin, webmin Even after searching on internet, I could not find a way to change the Swap size. Various online tutorials only showed us how to create swap space but did not explicitly address how to change the size of swap space using Webmin. Of course, this tutorial does not use Webmin but instead it uses commands against the server.

> Prerequisites/Assumptions

```
Swap space already exists
/swapfile is the file created for swap space
I am changing the /swapfile from 270MB to 1GB
```

> Commands to Resize Swap Space

```
sudo swapoff /swapfile
sudo fallocate -l 1G /swapfile
ls -lh /swapfile
sudo mkswap /swapfile
sudo swapon /swapfile
free
```

> Command Explanation

```
Turns off/unmounts current swap
Resizes swap file to 1G (or your desired size)
Verifies the file size and permission. (Make sure permission is -rw——-)
Marks this file as swap file. Without this command, system will use previous size
Turns on swap file
check free space
```